# How to glue two queries from nested for loop in one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Can I merge this to one query and make it faster 
I have table Person and Cart(id in tables is inherited from Base model)

```
class PersonModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    username = Column(String(30), nullable=True, default=None)
    email = Column(String(75), nullable=True, default=None)
    password = Column(String(128), nullable=True, default=None)

class CartModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'carts'
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    text = Column(String(300), nullable=True)
    began_at = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    ended_at = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False, default=utc_time)
    datetime = Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.now())
    money = Column(Float, default=0)
    quantity = Column(Integer, default=0)
```

and I need to find usernames from persons and quantity from  carts for all carts which happened since time t.

```
result = []
for c in session.query(CartModel).filter(CartMode.ended_at >= t).all():
    p = session.query(PersonModel).filter(PersonModel.id == c.person_id).first()
    if p:
      result.append((p.username, c.quantity))
```

How to glue this to one query ?

Answer (score 0):

```
session.query(CartModel).join(CartModel.person_id).filter(CartMode.ended_at >= t).all()
```

refer to this part in the docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-joins

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bpergo's answer, I recommend you build a relationship. I give you a quick solution, but I highly recommend to read [Relationship Configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html). This is one of the most valueable documentation on an already very good documentation.

In short: The idea of a relationship is that SQLAlchemy can automatically build the query you need:

```
class PersonModel(Base):
    ...
    carts = relationship("CartModel", backref="person")
```

With this modification you can very easily do this:

```
for c in session.query(CartModel).filter(CartMode.ended_at >= t):
    p = c.person
    ...
```

However, you have to pay attention: With only this solution, you will end up with a possibly high number of queries (see: [Relationship Loading Techniques](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/loading.html)). Instead do this, which will emit far less queries:

```
for c in session.query(CartModel).option(joinedload(PersonModel)).filter(CartModel.ended_at >= t):
    p = c.person
    ...
```

No I am sure this is not directly easy to understand. But I assure you, it is worth the read as SQLAlchemy can really take **a lot** of work of your hands if you have understood relationships.